# How to get product manufacturer name from manufacturer value id by mysql?

Tags: magento

I know how to get the product manufacturer id, but I need the product manufacturer id & name using MySQL.

`75` is the attribute id for getting product manufacturer id.

Anyone can help?

I want it in SQL format.

Comment: I assume Magneto has a fixed schema or we stand no chance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I want to get this out of the way.
If you have the product as an object you can get the manufacturer id like this:

```
$product->getManufacturer();
```

and for the name:

```
$product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Now for the sql part...I don't know why you would need it but here goes.
Let's say the product id is 10.
Try this query.

```
SELECT
    i.value as manufacturer_id,
    v.value as manufacturer_name
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_int i
    LEFT JOIN 
        eav_attribute_option o 
        ON i.value = o.option_id
    LEFT JOIN
        eav_attribute_option_value v
        ON o.option_id = v.option_id AND
        v.store_id = 0
WHERE 
    i.entity_id = 10 AND
    i.attribute_id = 75 AND 
    i.store_id = 0;
```

if you want the values for an other store view just replace the 0 in `v.store_id = 0` and `i.store_id = 0` with the value of your store id. 0 means default values.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question  isnt't i.value  is unique for different store?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I will try anyway. There is a unique index on the `catalog_product_entity_int` on the combination of these fields: `entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`. So for a product and a store id you can have a single value for `attribute_id`. The value does not have any constraints in the table  `catalog_product_entity_int`

Comment: Didn't find that this query worked because the entity_id and attribute_id for manufacturer is different in each store. However, the SQL code did hit on the `eav_attribute_option_value` and that is where the manufacturer name is. +1. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score -1):

Great code, thanks!

On my Magento 2.3.1 i have just changed attribute_id to '83' and added SKU. It works correctly.

```
SELECT
e.sku as SKU,
i.value as manufacturer_id,
v.value as manufacturer_name
FROM
catalog_product_entity_int i
LEFT JOIN
eav_attribute_option o
ON i.value = o.option_id
LEFT JOIN
eav_attribute_option_value v
ON o.option_id = v.option_id AND
v.store_id = 0
LEFT JOIN
catalog_product_entity e
ON i.entity_id = e.entity_id
WHERE
i.attribute_id = 83 AND
i.store_id = 0
ORDER BY `SKU`  DESC
```